# How do I search public status updates within a certain location?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to figure out the Graph API, and would like to be able to search through public status updates for specific strings, but only if the status originated from a certain city/place/location. Is this possible? I was thinking if I could find the place_id of a venue or location then I could search the 'status' DB table from there, but I have not been able to figure out the correct search key for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook says:

> Status search type does not support limit/offset paging.

So the answer would be no, at this time it is not possible to limit to a certain location.

Source https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/